# Python Mutagen ID3 library shows No AttributeError (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, id3, mutagen

i want to update **.mp3** songs ID3 tags with my own audio metadata. i want use ID3 v2.3. When i execute code it shows error

> AttributeError: 'ID3' object has no attribute 'COMM'

Please check my code and let me know how to fix this issue, and one more thing, is this possible i can completely remove old id3 metadata tags ? and update with my owns ?

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TPE2, COMM, USLT, TCOM, TCON, TDRC

filename = "Sanam Re.mp3"

audio = ID3(filename, translate=False)

keep_these = audio.getall("TSOP")
audio.update_to_v23()
audio.setall("TSOP", keep_these)

audio.add(TALB(encoding=3, text=u"Sanam Re"))  # Album Name
audio.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text=u"Dhoop Mein Na Chal - SongsBlig")) # Songs Title
audio.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text=u"Arjit Singh"))  # Singer Name
audio.add(TDRC(encoding=3, text=u"2015")) # Album Year
audio.add(TCON(encoding=3, text=u"Bollywood Music"))  # GENRE
audio.COMM(encoding=3, lang=u'eng', desc='desc', text=u'Downloaded') # Comment

audio.save(v2_version=3)
```

Comment: Did you miss the `.add` in the second-last line?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, it fixed the error, but still this tag not saved in mp3 file. second, how i can remove old id3 tags and replace with fresh  once.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is years old.  But,  To [@daniel-roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)'s point you were missing the .add from your statement.

Your code should work like this.

```py
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TPE2, COMM, USLT, TCOM, TCON, TDRC

filename = "Sanam Re.mp3"

audio = ID3(filename, translate=False)

keep_these = audio.getall("TSOP")
audio.update_to_v23()
audio.setall("TSOP", keep_these)

audio.add(TALB(encoding=3, text=u"Sanam Re"))  # Album Name
audio.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text=u"Dhoop Mein Na Chal - SongsBlig")) # Songs Title
audio.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text=u"Arjit Singh"))  # Singer Name
audio.add(TDRC(encoding=3, text=u"2015")) # Album Year
audio.add(TCON(encoding=3, text=u"Bollywood Music"))  # GENRE
audio.add(COMM(encoding=3, lang=u'eng', desc='desc', text=u'Downloaded')) # Comment

audio.save(v2_version=3)

for i, j in audio.items():
    print(f"{i} = \"{j}\"")

# ============================================
# Returns Successfully.
# ============================================

# TIT2 = "Dhoop Mein Na Chal - SongsBlig"
# TPE1 = "Arjit Singh"
# TALB = "Sanam Re"
# TCON = "Bollywood Music"
# PCNT = "PCNT(count=393)"
# TYER = "2015"
# COMM:desc:eng = "Downloaded"
# TDRC = "2015"
```